# How to do nonlinear complex root finding in Python

Tags: python, scipy, mathematical-optimization

I want to do a root search for the following nonlinear equations, I do it in Python but it doesn't work. my code is below

```
from pylab import *
import scipy
import scipy.optimize

def z1(x,y):
    temp=1+1j+x+2*y;
    return temp

def z2(x,y):
    temp=-1j-2*x+sqrt(3)*y;
    return temp

def func(x):
    temp=[z1(x[0],x[1])-1.0/(1-1.0/(z2(x[0],x[1]))),1-2.0/(z2(x[0],x[1])-4.0/z1(x[0],x[1]))]
    return temp

result=scipy.optimize.fsolve(func,[1+1j,1+1j])

print result
```

when I run it, it shows errors:

---> 30 result=scipy.optimize.fsolve(func,[1+1j,1+1j])

C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\minpack.py in fsolve(func, x0, args, fprime, full_output, col_deriv, xtol, maxfev, band, epsfcn, factor, diag)

```
123             maxfev = 200*(n + 1)

124         retval = _minpack._hybrd(func, x0, args, full_output, xtol,
```

--> 125                 maxfev, ml, mu, epsfcn, factor, diag)

```
126     else:

127         _check_func('fsolve', 'fprime', Dfun, x0, args, n, (n,n))
```

Comment: it is due to the complex number unit "j", it seems fsolve can only search root for real equations and return real roots??!

Answer (score 6):

`fsolve` finds zeros of functions from R^n -> R. The similar function [`root`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.root.html#scipy.optimize.root) finds zeros of functions from R^n -> R^m.

It looks like you're trying to find zeros of a function from C^2 -> C^2, which as far as I know scipy.optimize doesn't support directly - but you could try writing it a function from R^4 -> R^4 and then using `root`. For example, something along the lines of:

```
def func_as_reals(x):
    r1, c1, r2, c2 = x
    a, b = func([complex(r1, c1), complex(r2, c2)])
    return [a.real, a.imag, b.real, b.imag]
```

should work, though it might be significantly faster to do it directly on the real numbers instead of repeatedly wrapping into complex and unwrapping.

Comment: This is just an extremely simplified example for my real-solving problem. The real problem is a 5000 depth "fibonacci-like" fraction, but in C^2, so it seems no hope to rewrite that monster into R^4

Comment: by the way, why there is no .root under .optimize ? when I "tab" optimize. I can find .fsolve but there is no .root . I use Python27, academic version

Comment: What version of scipy do you have? `root` is new in 0.11, as the linked documentation says; since it seems like you're probably using EPD (since there's no such thing as an "academic version" of Python), it might still have an old version.

Comment: Of course, a point `x` is a zero of `f : R^n -> R^m` iff `|| f(x) || = 0`. So you could try `fsolve`ing the function that's like `func_as_reals` but instead returns `a.real**2 + a.imag**2 + b.real**2 + b.imag**2` instead.

Answer (score 4):

You could try mpmath's findroot([sympy](http://docs.sympy.org/0.7.0/modules/mpmath/calculus/optimization.html)):

```
from mpmath import findroot

#Your code here

ans = findroot([z1,z2],(0,0))
print(ans)
```

Returns:

```
[(-0.302169479251962 - 0.651084739625981j)]
[(-0.348915260374019 - 0.174457630187009j)]
```

which is a solution of your system.
Mpmath is a multiprecision library so it's routines are generally slower, but you could give it a try!