# Complex solvers in SciPy

Tags: scipy, mathematical-optimization, complex-numbers

Can the solvers in SciPy deal with complex values (i.e x=x'+i*x")?  I am specifically interested in using a Nelder-Mead type minimisation function.  I am usually a Matlab user and I know that Matlab does not have complex solvers.  If SciPy can do this then I'm a convert for sure!  Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by "complex solver"?  Comparison of two complex numbers is poorly defined since each "number" is two dimensional.  Consider x > y.  Is the answer real(x) > real(y), imag(x) > imag(y), |x| > |y|, angle(x) > angle(y), real(x)+imag(x) > real(y)+imag(y), or something else?

Comment: Does [this other Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15213141/how-to-do-nonlinear-complex-root-finding-in-python?rq=1) answer help you?

Answer (score 2):

It looks like neither `scipy.optimize.fmin` nor `scipy.optimize.leastsq` play nice with complex numbers. For example, `fmin(lambda x: np.linalg.norm(x - np.array((1.2, 3+2j))), np.array((0j, 0j)))` converges to `array([ 1.19996429,  2.99997809])` and `leastsq` just fails. To make it work, I'd embed your complex numbers in R^2, I guess. So like

```
fmin(lambda x: np.linalg.norm(x - np.array((1.2, 0, 3,2))), np.array((0,0, 0,0)))
```

which converges to

```
array([  1.20000095e+00,  -4.11719096e-05,   2.99999705e+00,    2.00001270e+00])
```

But yea, it would be nice if those functions did play nice with complex numbers.